# MySQL return a message: an empty result (ie no rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I dont understand why my sql return this error when i try to create event..

error: `# MySQL returned an empty result (ie no rows).`

Code:

```
USE my_database;
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `remove_inactives`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO

    DELETE FROM `inactive`
        WHERE `inactive` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
;
```

Comment: Please don't delete questions in order to post them again.

Comment: Have you try `DELETE FROM inactive WHERE inactive < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);` directly ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to the fact that your where clause is not referring to any columns in your `inactive` table and therefore

```
`inactive` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

produces no results.

I am not sure what your column name is, but for sake of argument let's assume it is last_mod_time, in which case this SQL statement might work:

```
DELETE FROM `inactive`
  WHERE `inactive`.last_mod_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

If you find that your events are still not being processed, use `SHOW PROCESSLIST\G` to see if event_scheduler is running.

If not, then use the following to start it for the currently-running mysqld session:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

To make the setting permanent so the scheduler starts when mysqld starts set the appropriate [server system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler)